# Giving both input & output file at command line

Tags: perl, file-io, stdout

Si I have this line in the perl script which prints the output to the STDOUT/console

```
printf "Line no. $i"
```

What code shall I include in the program to direct this output to an output file given by user at the command line itself (as undermentioned)

Right now ,the following portion asks the user for input file:

```
print "enter file name";
chomp(my $file=<STDIN>);
open(DATA,$file) or die "error reading";
```

But I  dont want to ask the user for either of input/output file.
What I want is a way in which user could give in the input as well as output file from command line while running the program.

```
perl input_file output_file program.pl
```

What code shall i just include for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift` to read the command line arguments to your script. `shift` reads and removes the first element of an array. If no array is specified (and not inside a subroutine), it will implicitly read from `@ARGV`, which contains the list of arguments passed to your script. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# check that two arguments have been passed
die "usage: $0 input output\n" unless @ARGV == 2;

my $infile = shift;
my $outfile = shift;

# good idea to sanitise the arguments here

open my $in, "<", $infile;
open my $out, ">", $outfile;

while (<$in>) {
    print $out $_;
}

close $in;
close $out;
```

You could call this script like `perl script.pl input_file output_file` and it would copy the contents of `input_file` to `output_file`.

Comment: Hi tom I did this(for certain reasons I need to read in the input in <DATA> format) : -  open my $in, "<", $infile;
open(DATA,$in);
open my $out, ">", $outfile;    Then to write the output I did this ====>   print $out "%-4s: %20s,   %-8s %6s\n", $_->[0], qq($_->[0]$_->[3]), $_->[2], $group{$_->[2]};

Comment: So you want to read from the file specified on the command line as well as from `__DATA__`? Please edit your question to add more detail.

Comment: @Sunita I see you are using my answer in your more recent question. Don't forget to upvote answers that you find useful and accept those that best answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach here is to ignore input and output files within your program. Just read from STDIN and write to STDOUT. Let the user redirect those filehandles when calling your program.

Your program looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<STDIN>) {
  # do something useful to the data in $_
  print;
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
$ ./your_program.pl inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

This is known as the "Unix Filter Model" and it's the most flexible way to write programs that read input and produce output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ARGV variable ,

```
use strict ; 
use warnings ;

if ( @ARGV != 2 ) 
{
        print "Usage : <program.pl> <input> <output>\n" ;
        exit ;
}
open my $Input,$ARGV[0] or die  "error:$!\n" ;
open my $Output,">>" .$ARGV[1] or die "error:$!\n";                         
print $Output $_  while (<$Input> )  ;
close ($Input) ;
close ($Output) ;
```

**Note:**
You should run the program `perl program.pl input_file output_file` this format.

Comment: Yes, except you should really sanitize that input first. Otherwise, bad things can and will happen, even if unintentional.  Also, you should avoid using bare word file descriptors (potential for other bad side effects)

Comment: @vol7ron,Can you please tell me what is the side effect?

Comment: Deleting files, crashing disks, using up all the memory, reading what should be secure/restricted data, etc.  External inputs are the easiest way in to your system.